# How to convert an array to an escaped string, which I can use in a regex?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, preg-match

I'm querying for subnets from a database. Ultimately I'll get a bunch of subnets into an array of strings with results like:

```
array = ['10.1.0.1/24', '10.2.0.2/24', '192.168.0.8/16']
```

What's the best way to join the array above and ensure all `.` and `/` are properly escaped so I can see if a string I have matches any one of the subnets in the array?

Ideally I'd have something like:

```
if (preg_match(array_as_string, $buffer, $matches)) { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can loop through all array values with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and escape them with [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php). After this you can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to make them to a string, e.g.

```
$array = array_map(function($ip){
    return preg_quote($ip, "/");
}, $array);

if (preg_match("/\b(" . implode("|", $array) . ")\b/", $buffer, $matches)) { }
```

So you will end up with a regex like this:

```
/\b(10\.1\.0\.1\/24|10\.2\.0\.2\/24|192\.168\.0\.8\/16)\b/
```